# Unable to assign the type unknown to an entity with typeorm

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm having issues using TypeOrm with typescript for a specific project. It seems that typescript is not able to recognize a type coming out from a typeorm entity.

```
@Entity({
name: "users",
  synchronize: false
})
export default class User {

  private tempPassword:string | undefined;

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({
    type: "text"
  })
  name!: string;
...
}
```

The code above is my model. So when I try :

```
let user: UserModel;
try {
  user = await getRepository("User").findOne({name: "test"});
```

I have the following error on the user variable :
[image: Error]

(Which means : unable to assign the type unknown to the type User)

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ES2018",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./src",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           
    "esModuleInterop": true,                   

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```

Is it due to something missing in the tsconfig json ? Big thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `strict: true` meaning you have to also check for `null` / `undefined`.

`let user: UserModel | undefined`;

Edit:

I'm thinking that the `getRepository(string)` signature returns `unknown` (you can assert its result if you want - `as User`). Try, `getRepository(User)...`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Even tho it now gets me the error "Unable to assign the type unknown to the type User | undefined. Then I tried after removing the strict mode and now I have "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, name.ts(2740)

Comment: You can describe repository type when trying to get it. getRepository<User>("User").findOne or you can directly reach the repository by User.getRepository().findOne

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the string from `getRepository("User")` to `getRepository(User)`. Import the entity to the file where you call the repository and use it as a parameter on the function `getRepository()`.

Also, I assume that you have a row in your DB with a user with the name "test". If not try to add it and then look for it, although `findOne()` returns null when none row matches.

Another option is to use the `queryBuilder()` on the repository.